# How to get pixel colour of screen? (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to retrieve the colour of a pixel on the screen in C in Rasbmc (Raspberry Pi)? 
My plan is to use this along with WiringPi to control RGB LEDs according to the averaged colour at certain points on the screen.

I've looked into various options including using Python. One site provides examples which seems useful but I am yet to make them work. I have tried both the Python and [C Examples](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#C).

The code I am using is the following:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

void get_pixel_color (Display *d, int x, int y, XColor *color)
{
    XImage *image;
    image = XGetImage (d, RootWindow (d, DefaultScreen (d)), x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes, XYPixmap);
    color->pixel = XGetPixel (image, 0, 0);
    XFree (image);
    XQueryColor (d, DefaultColormap(d, DefaultScreen (d)), color);
}


XColor c;
get_pixel_color(display, 30, 40, &c);
printf ("%d %d %d\n", c.red, c.green, c.blue);
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. These are the errors I get when I use the C example:

[image: Error Message]

What I don't understand is the first error I get (the others seem to be related to the formating of the printf function so I guess they can be ignored?). What does it mean by numeric constants, does it mean the x and y components of the get_pixel_color function? That seems weird to me but I know I must be misunderstanding something here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to get_pixelcolor isn't in a function.

You seem to be lacking a main function altogether, unless I'm missing something completely.  You're calling functions OUTSIDE of a program block.  In C, that formatting is reserved for prototyping.  Your compiler is expecting a prototype (Prototyping is describing a function roughly, "takes these arguments, returns this" , before you actually describe the implementation of it. If you're unfamiliar with the terminology.) , when you're feeding it a function.

At the very least you're looking at:

```
int main(){
    XColor c;
    get_pixel_color(display, 30, 40, &c);
    printf ("%d %d %d\n", c.red, c.green, c.blue);
    return 0;
}
```

Give that a try, and see if it works.

If this is part of a larger program which already has a main, just call the function something different and call it from main.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me move forward! The code I showed in my first post was literelly the example from the site because I thought it could be run straight away. It now makes sense why it doesnt just run by itself.. I'm now getting an error saying the display variable hasnt been declared. I assume it wants my screen resolution or something like that. Ill investigate some more. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: No, your code doesn't actually declare a display variable.  You use a variable called "display" but it isn't actually created anywhere.  If you look at the function (get_pixel_color(Display*, int, int, Xcolor*) ) you can see that it is expecting a pointer to a Display type variable.[link](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) should get you started.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. After looking around for examples this is what I came up with however, while it seems to compile correctly, I get the error "segmentation fault". From what I understand this could be a pointer issue? I am looking at Grabc source code for inspiration. Intersetingly enough, it seems like it uses the exact same method i am with a lot more stuff added for mouse click detection etc. The pointers are the same, along with other things and I am stumpped! here's my code so far: http://pastebin.com/4ibmWWeA sorry for using pastebin, cant paste it in here

Comment: I think you should probably take a look at the return value from XOpenDisplay (i.e. if(display == NULL)).  Looking at the xlib documentation, it says that the function returns NULL on failure.  Passing a null value into the get_pixel_color function may generate a segfault if it doesn't check the pointer.  Another note, why did you decide to pass in a zero to the getDisplay() function?  Reading the docs page says that on POSIX compliant systems, the default display is accessed by calling getDisplay(NULL);  Give that a try.

Comment: I was using that because I saw it on some other site. Ive sice changed it to NULL and implemented a check to see the value returned by XOpenDIsplay. It appears to return NULL! So somehting is wrong with the detection of the display? Will look into it some more. Updated code: http://pastebin.com/dMyydxhx

Comment: I think I found what's wrong. From what I understand, Raspbmc doesnt use X11 and since the code I'm using is based on X11 stuff (I think), it makes sense why XOpenDisplay doesnt find a display! Back to square one...

Answer (score 1):

Is this your actual .c file, or just a snippet?  If it your actual file (judging by the line numbers, it is), then you will need to put the last three lines in a [main() function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function):

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    XColor c;
    get_pixel_color(display, 30, 40, &c);
    printf ("%d %d %d\n", c.red, c.green, c.blue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the actual .c file. Thanks to you and Happington I managed to move forward! Just need to sort out something to do with the display variable now.